# How come NullReferenceException is more expensive than any other exception in CLR?

Tags: c#, nullpointerexception, clr

While looking for null check vs catching NullReferenceException, I came across this.

> Catching a null dereference is one of the most expensive operations that the CLR can perform, and this could have a severe performance impact if your code is throwing a lot of NullReferenceExceptions. Testing for nullity and doing something else about it (even throwing an exception!) is a cheaper operation.
>
> Here is a link of the question where I found it. [When is handling a null pointer/reference exception preferred over doing a null check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374611/when-is-handling-a-null-pointer-reference-exception-preferred-over-doing-a-null)

I am wondering how can catching NullReferenceException be more expensive than null check and throwing exception.

[couldn't comment there because of insufficient reputation numbers]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The point here is not that a `NullReferenceException` is more expensive than any other exception. The cost of throwing exceptions comes from unrolling the stack and that depends more on the call structure than the specific exception. I believe the point the doc is trying to make is that it is less expensive to safe-guard against the exception in the first place, than it is to handle it when its thrown.

Answer (score 2):

A `NullReferenceException` is a ***Hardware Exception*** and it is handled by the Windows Page Fault handler first.  This operation requires a [kernel context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch), which can be a very expensive operation depending on the underlying CPU hardware and also the operating system security model.  Furthermore, the Garbage Collector typically must suspend certain operations until the context switch has been completed.  Since the GC services all threads and app domains, any time the GC spends in suspension can result in potentially significant performance hits that only surface at unexpected intervals.

By comparison, throwing your own exception from within C# via the `throw` keyword generates a ***Software Exception***.  These require no special processing and in cases where the `catch` handler of the exception is local (within the same function), can be optimized further, since no additional unwinding is needed to discover the appropriate catch handler.  This is why the MSDN docs recommend against relying on `NullReferenceException`.

It's hard to give concrete values on performance differences since there are so many variables at play.  In a worst case I could imagine it could be near a magnitude slower -- eg, able to throw and catch perhaps a hundred local software exceptions in the time it takes to process a single hardware exception.  In practice though I'd guess performance ratio something in the vicinity of 3:1 to 10:1, depending on CPU, OS, C# CLR, and number of active threads sharing the Heap/GC.